# Two A records while I switch servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, web-server, dreamhost

I am frantically running from dreamhost and their horrible products - but this leaves me with a interesting situation:

1 Website is 'fully hosted' through their webpanel
- this auto creates the 'A' record to their server
- this points to the correct folder where the web files are at

2 New site has been tested and ready to receive web traffic

3 clicking 'dns only' removes the A and allows me to point it to the new record, but also removes the web folder location

4 thus when a client hits the old A record they are pointed at a silly robot error message that the website has gone missing instead of rendering the old site.

5 I have request them to modify the apache file, modify the A record, do something for me and they could care less and tell me to have a "great day!"

What can I do to have a better transition away from this horrible company?
Can I supply both A records, and then yank the one out in a day? Do I need to move the nameservers to a new server and try and tackle this from a different angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your nameservers to somewhere else, so that you can leave Dreamhost's settings like they are currently.

Then change the A record on the new nameserver.